# Create Azure IoT Hub devices

Tags: .net, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to create new devices on Azure IoT Hub programatically with .NET? With all tutorial on microsoft.docs the devices are created via Azure Portal or Azure CLI.

Could you kindly provide some interesting links if you have? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's in `RegistryManager`, `AddDeviceAsync()`, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager.adddeviceasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_RegistryManager_AddDeviceAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Device_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tutorial for [creating a device identity](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/iot-hub-get-started-create-device-identity-csharp.md) you can follow.

The related API is `registryManager.AddDeviceAsync`.

```
    RegistryManager manager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

    await manager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceID));
```

You can find the [C# code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/service/samples/ConsoleSample/Program.cs) at Azure IoT SDK C# repo on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

also, you can use an [IoT Hub REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/)

- the following is an implementation of the [Create Or Update Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createorupdatedevice):

  ```
      string connectionString = "<yourIoTHubConnectionString>";
      string deviceId = "<yourDeviceId>";

      string iothubName = SharedAccessSignatureBuilder.GetHostNameNamespaceFromConnectionString(connectionString);
      string sasToken = SharedAccessSignatureBuilder.GetSASTokenFromConnectionString(connectionString);
      string requestUri = $"https://{iothubName}.azure-devices.net/devices/{deviceId}?api-version=2018-06-30";

      var httpclient = new HttpClient();
      httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sasToken);

      var hrm = httpclient.PutAsJsonAsync(requestUri, new { deviceId = deviceId }).Result;
      hrm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string response = hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  ```

where a SharedAccessSignatureBuilder is a helper static class:

```
public sealed class SharedAccessSignatureBuilder
{ 
    public static string GetHostNameNamespaceFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return GetPartsFromConnectionString(connectionString)["HostName"].Split('.').FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static string GetSASTokenFromConnectionString(string connectionString, uint hours = 24)
    {
        var parts = GetPartsFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        return GetSASToken(parts["HostName"], parts["SharedAccessKey"], parts["SharedAccessKeyName"], hours);
    }
    public static string GetSASToken(string resourceUri, string key, string keyName = null, uint hours = 24)
    {
        var expiry = GetExpiry(hours);
        string stringToSign = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(key));

        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName))
            sasToken += String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "&skn={0}", keyName); 

        return sasToken;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetPartsFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return connectionString.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
    }

    // default expiring = 24 hours
    private static string GetExpiry(uint hours = 24)
    {
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        return Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600 * hours);
    }
}
```